# Is it possible to have only one consul server to serve key-pairs for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, consul

I would like to know if it is possible to server consul server key-value pairs with only one consul server.

I am trying to setup consul server for only storing key value pairs for my rails app. I am setting up only one consul server which will act as agent. However getting problems in setting up the web-ui of consul.

I tried to run one physical instance as a consul server to serve the web-ui of consul

```
consul agent -server -data-dir /tmp/consul -ui-dir /home/ubuntu/dist/
```

Than to access the consul web-ui on the public ip I run the following command

```
consul members -rpc-addr=X.X.X.X:8400
```

Got the following error

```
Error connecting to Consul agent: dial tcp X.X.X.X:8400: connection refused
```

Where X.X.X.X is the private ip of the instance

Comment: Yes, it's possible to start single server instance to have a Key/Value store. I think, you need to provide more information about a configuration and a problem you have

Comment: @Stanislav To start the single server for storing key-value pairs. How to use the single physical instance? as a server agent or as a client agent? as I need to have consul web-ui also

Comment: @Stanislav Please see the edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default agent is starting a client at localhost, due to documentation:

> Client Addr: This is the address used for client interfaces to the agent. This includes the ports for the HTTP, DNS, and RPC interfaces. The RPC address is used by other consul commands (such as consul members, consul join, etc) which query and control a running agent. By default, this binds only to localhost. If you change this address or port, you'll have to specify a -rpc-addr whenever you run commands such as consul members to indicate how to reach the agent. Other applications can also use the RPC address and port to control Consul.

So you need to set a flag `-client=X.X.X.X` to set IP address for remote access to the client. Try to start your server with this command:

```
consul agent -server -bootstrap -data-dir /tmp/consul -ui-dir /home/ubuntu/dist/ -client=X.X.X.X
```

Where X.X.X.X your IP address. To check that option is accepted, check the server output, it contains a line like:

```
 Client Addr: X.X.X.X(HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600, RPC: 8400)
```

And to access to the WebUI, open in your web browser this link: http://X.X.X.X:8500/ui

As for `consul members` command, it just prints you a list of known members by this agent, so there is no need to execute it, to use WebUI.

Comment: Would like to add one more thing, with the command above, we will be able to access the web-ui but won't be able to access the services or key-value or any other feature of consul server because the server we started with the above command will not elect itself as leader. So we need to start it with the bootstrap option.
consul agent -server -bootstrap -data-dir /tmp/consul -ui-dir /home/ubuntu/dist/ -client=X.X.X.X

Comment: Sure, too long didn't use it as standalone and totally forgot about it

Comment: I was trying to enable ACLs also, so I made a config.json file in /etc/consul.d/bootstrap/ directory mentioning the "acl_datacenter": "dc1" it doesn't enable it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but it is not a very good idea. Consul is optimized to operate in a distributed architecture where tolerance to a Network Partition is a primary concern. With just one node you would be much better severed with something like Redis. It will be much faster and scale to a larger set of clients. Read up on [CAP Theorum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

- Redis is optimized for Consistency and Availability.
- Consul is optimized for Availability and Partition Tolerance (if run as a Cluster).

With a single node there is no reason to use Consul for K/V's, although if you also wanted it's Service Discovery, DNS, Events, and Locking features then there is a reason.